# Sencha Architect (touch) - Use camera photos

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have implemented my sencha architect project with a possibility to do a photo (with phonegap). After taking a photo, I need to see the photo directly into another container with other information (the picture will be smaller than the original...and there will be written above and below).

How do I open the new container and display the image in a smaller size?
please help me, I don't understand how can I manage the photo

Now I use this code but if you have something better....

```
var me = this;
  Ext.device.Camera.capture({
     success: function(image) {
        me.add({
        xtype:'image', // Commento
        src: image
        });
   },
source: 'camera',
cameraDirection: navigator.camera.Direction.FRONT,
destination: 'file'bu
});
```

thank you
Carlo

Answer (score 0):

Sencha documentation got an example for it. See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
   success: function(image) {
      imageView.setSrc(image);
   },
   quality: 75,
   width: 200,
   height: 200,
   destination: 'data'
});
```

You can also use

```
destination: 'url'
```

in that case the image argument of the callback function will be a file URL what you can use in a container template as the source of the html image.